# how to create Hollow triangle in css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want create hollow triangle with `CSS` but I don't how to hollow that. I can create triangle with `CSS` but I have one problem and this is: I can't hollow this triangle.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tringle"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tringle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 7px;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid white;
}
```

Comment: my friend look this post maybe help you...

[create-triangle-with-css][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231184/create-triangle-with-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly cross-browser but works. Hope I've understood your request.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmDNr/3/

```
 .triangle { 
     position: relative;
     width: 20px;
     margin-top: 100px;
 }
 .triangle>div { 
     width: 20px;
     height: 2px;
     background: red;
     margin-top: 100px;
 }

 .triangle>div:before {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     width: 20px;
     height: 2px;
     background: red;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(56deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(56deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(56deg);
     transform: rotate(56deg);
     position: absolute;
     top: -8px;
     right: -5px;
 }
 .triangle>div:after {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     width: 20px;
     height: 2px;
     background: red;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-56deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-56deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-56deg);
     transform: rotate(-56deg);
     position: absolute;
     top: -8px;
     left: -5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have solution but i have workaround with two triangle, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aDcTb/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="tringle"></div>
<div id="tringle2"></div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
    #tringle {
        left:10px;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 100px solid transparent;
        border-right: 100px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 100px solid black;
    }
    #tringle2 {

        left:10px;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 50px solid #FFF;
        left: 57px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Forking off rajesh kakawat - you can get the same effect with one div: http://jsfiddle.net/aDcTb/

```
<div id="triangle"></div>

#triangle {
        left:10px;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 100px solid transparent;
        border-right: 100px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 100px solid black;
    }
    #triangle:after {
        left:10px;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 50px solid #FFF;
        left: 57px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;
        content: '';
    }
```