# CSS triangle how to remove white space on the right

Tags: css, geometry, polygon

I'm implementing a CSS triangle but it has whitespace on the right. I would like to display some text on the right of the triangle.
I have tried editing the margin and the padding but had no success yet. I found other examples of CSS triangles like [this one](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle) which also have whitespace on the right.

Anyone got a suggestion how to remove this?

I used http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

with this CSS code

```
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 35px 22.5px 0 22.5px;
border-color: #ff5154 transparent transparent transparent;
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/g3b6w/

Comment: What do you mean by whitespace? It seems ok to me. http://jsfiddle.net/g3b6w/1/

Comment: What you really want is to have a text to the right of the triangle? This is just the positioning of the element and nothing more.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle with an example. I would like the figures to be displayed right next to the arrow. But the whitespace next to the arrow keeps pushing the figures down. http://jsfiddle.net/g3b6w/5/

Comment: Just float both elements, and change order, triangle goes after the `.figures-negative` element

Comment: You could use a [text-only solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16231703/1437016), just remove the `-webkit-text-stroke`, and you'll have an inlined triangle (you could even make a pseudo-element containing your triangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css.

```
.triangle {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can use float property.

```
.triangle {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the text to the right by using **display: inline-block;** See http://jsfiddle.net/ben1/g3b6w/6/

```
display: inline-block;
```