# How to draw a circle inside a right angled triangle in html page?

Tags: html, css, geometry, polygon, css-shapes

Is it possible to draw a circle inside a right angled triangle in an HTML page using CSS.
Is it also possible to put some text inside it?

The output should be something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that can hopefully get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/8mfx9qhj

I always end up back at https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/ when trying to do things like this with CSS. If you're looking to draw a more complex diagram like the image above, I'd recommend doing it with SVG and some drawing library (e.g. http://snapsvg.io/) instead, which will make the job a lot easier.

Code from linked jsfiddle:

```
<div id="triangle">
  <div id="circle">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#triangle {
  position: relative;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;

  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 16px;

  border-radius: 50%;

  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Output:

[image: trianglecircle]

Comment: Is there any way to draw that diagram without SVG ?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but will be extremely finicky. Lots of absolute positioning and manual px-adjustment. You could use two overlapping triangles (one red, one white slightly smaller) to achieve the triangle outline, then two overlapping circles (one blue, one white slightly smaller) to get the circle outline. The green lines would need to be absolutely positioned and css `transform: rotate(Ndeg)` divs which will be extremely tedious to implement.

Any reason you can't use SVG? Has browser support in all but very old versions of IE and Android Browser: https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Okay, I'll use SVG as you said.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see lots of css and nested html is needed to create the shape. As @evnp said
SVG would make your life easier.

```css
#right-triangle-red {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 300px solid red;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
}

#right-trianlg-white {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 276px solid white;
  border-right: 461px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 16px;
  left: 10px;
}

.triangles {
  position: relative;
}

#circle-purple {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#circle-white {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

#circle-green {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  top: 86px;
  left: 86px;
}

.circles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  top: -207px;
  left: 10px;
}

.label {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

.label-b {
  top: -219px;
  left: 510px;
}

.label-c {
  top: -205px;
  left: -31px;
}

.label-d {
  color: green;
  top: -341px;
  left: 64px;
}

.shape-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="label label-a">
  A
</span>

<div class="shape-container">

  <div class="triangles">
    <div id="right-triangle-red">
      <div id="right-trianlg-white">
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class="circles">
    <div id="circle-purple">
      <div id="circle-white">
        <div id="circle-green">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
  
</div>

<span class="label label-b">
  B
</span>

<span class="label label-c">
  C
</span>

<span class="label label-d">
  D
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will consider [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484262/8620333) to draw the triangle and will add another gradient for the circle

```css
.triangle {
  --t:10;    /* Thickness */
  --c:black; /* Color */
  --r:25px;  /* Radius*/

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:calc(var(--t)*1px) solid transparent;
  border-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,
      transparent 49.5%,var(--c) 50%) var(--t);
  background:
    /* Left side */
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,
      transparent 49.5%,var(--c) 50% calc(50% + var(--t)*1px),
      transparent calc(50% + var(--t)*1px + 1px)),
    /* circle */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at var(--r) calc(100% - var(--r)),
      transparent calc(100% - 5px), yellow calc(100% - 4px) 99%,transparent 100%);
  background-origin:border-box,padding-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>

<div class="triangle" style="--t:5;--c:blue;width:150px;--r:33px;"></div>

<div class="triangle" style="--t:8;--c:red;height:150px;--r:31px;"></div>

<div class="triangle" style="--t:15;--c:green;width:80px;--r:20px"></div>
```

You simply need some math to calculate the radius. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247599/695610

As you can see, it's a simple div at the end so you can write your content inside it and align it like you want