# Rotate triangle with around centre point CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my project:

```css
body {
  background-color: #312a50;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  color: white;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.t1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 86.6px solid blue;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="text-align: center;" class="wrapper">
    <div class="t1 rotating"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My triangle currently rotates fine, and at the right speed, but it isn't rotating at the centre point of the triangle. It seems to rotate from a point slightly off from the centre.

Also, how do I show only the border of the triangle and not the full solid blue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the transform-origin to `50% 66%`

```css
body {
  background-color: #312a50;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  color: white;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.t1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 86.6px solid blue;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  transform-origin: 50% 66%;
}


@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="text-align: center;" class="wrapper">
    <div class="t1 rotating"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks - how do I add a transparent fill but with a border-color of blue (5px width)?

Comment: @WazowskiMan check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484262/8620333